# how to put app icon near player controller iOS tray?

Tags: iphone, ios4, internet-radio, tray

im not sure the screen's name is iOS system tray when home button doble clicked.

my radio app supports background plays. everything is ok.

when double clickte home button, and scroll to left, there is player control, and i cant see my app icon just near the player control.

i have seen many radio apps, their icons are just right side of the player control.

my screen shows rotate button, player buttons and ipod icon(or empty).

any help please...

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the audio session, so that iOS knows that you are playing audio. This snippet will do the trick (don't forget to read the documentation!)

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:NULL];
```

Also, don't forget to set `audio` as a background mode that your app supports.

Comment: UIBackgroundModes --> audio  and i have already put your code in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions event. radio plays on background, no problem. icon is still NOT shown.

Comment: Are you listening for remote events? `[[UIApplication SharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];`

Comment: Whenever you are able to respond to remote control events. My audio app calls it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.